# WCF to WCF calls via channel factory getting queued either in first or second application

Tags: performance, wcf, concurrency, iis-8, .net-4.5.2

I have a couple of WCF .net 4.5.2 application hosted in IIS 8.5 in windows 2012 r2. Both services application are on different system. My first WCF application handle multiple Requests from outside. This WCF service itself work with second WCF service application via channel factory. Problem I am having is that during bulk testing there seems to be some problem in WCF call from application one to reach in application 2.Via log what i see is that there is even 25+ seconds is passing in reaching the calls from app1 o app2. What i want's to identify is that whether queuing is in application one or two?Can somebody suggest me how can i check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that problem were due to log4net ado net appender entries. I have increase the property BufferSize which help in improving the throughput. If there is better suggestion then please let me know.